# create two entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Maybe what I´m going to ask it´s a silly question, what I wan to know if it is possible in a Spring MVC configuration has two entityManagerFactory. I will explain why.

I have one LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean where I configure a hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver which I use to determine the tenant by LDAP using the session of the user, and then use one database Schema or another, then I use "multi_tenant_connection_provider" to create the database connection for that schema. 
Now my application has a Scheduler that needs access to all Schemas and get some information from all databases. So in order to do not touch the entityManagerFactory already configure, what I was thinking was to create a new one with my own implementation of "hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" to control which schema I want instead LDAP, before create the database connection by "multi_tenant_connection_provider".
the problem looks like Spring do not allow me configure two entityManagerFactory. 
Can you give me any advice about how to achieve what I want?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The issue was becuase I´m using Spring data, and my repositories did not which EntityManagerFactory use. As soon as I specify which one to use during the scan everything works like a charm.

```
         <repositories base-package="com.*.*.repository**" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use multiple EntityManagers.
In my project I use the annotation configuration, where I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public SessionFactory smartDataSessionFactory() {
    return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(smartDataDatasource())
            .scanPackages("...)
            .addProperties(smartDataHibernateProperties())
            .buildSessionFactory();
}


@Bean
public SessionFactory analysisSessionFactory() {
    return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(analysisDatasource())
            .scanPackages("...)
            .addProperties(analysisHibernateProperties())
            .buildSessionFactory();
}
    ...
}
```

When referencing the entityManagers, be sure to use the Qualifier annotation.
Also note that each SessionFactory will use it's own TransactionFactory

```
@Repository
@Transactional(value = "analysisTransactionManager")
public class ToURemunerationDaoImpl implements ToURemunerationDao {
    private SessionFactory analysisSessionFactory;

    private SessionFactory smartDataSessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("analysisSessionFactory")
    public void setAnalysisSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.analysisSessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("smartDataSessionFactory")
    public void setSmartDataSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.smartDataSessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    ...
}
```